# How to deal with words out of the vocabulary CBOW implementation

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec

I'm studying word2vec theory, and I decided to implement the Continuous Bag of Words model from zero.

I know the primary pipeline for this:

- Preprocess a corpus: remove stopwords, lemmatization, etc.
- Creates a vocabulary from the preprocess corpus (this vocabulary may have fewer tokens than the entire corpus).
- Coding the neural network architecture using Pytorch, Keras, etc.
- Then, training the model using the preprocess corpus.
- Finally, check the quality of the word embedding using a downstream NLP task, such as analogy, word similarity, etc.

The inputs for the CBOW are the target word and its contexts. **But what happens when the algorithm reviews a sequence of texts and encounters a target word or contexts words that are out of the vocabulary? Does the model ignore these words?**

Thank!